# Dynamic initial value for the username using forms and views from django.contrib.auth

Tags: django, authentication, dry

I am presently using the `login`  view and the `AuthenticationForm` from `django.contrib.auth.views` to login users.

Now, I would like to extend this solution to prepopulate the `username` field from the `request` object (I can infer the username if visitors are authenticated elsewhere). Because I am lazy and would like to keep *dry*, I wonder if this is possible without replicating the entire login view code.

I am aware of [dynamic initial values](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) in Django, but I cannot see how these might be passed into the [login view](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) (which does not accept form instances as parameter).
 On the IRC channel, it was suggested that I extend the `AuthenticationForm` to process the request, however (as far as I understand), the request is *not* always passed on to the form (rather only when the form is submitted, which would be too late).

The only alternative I can think of is writing a custom login view to add initial values, which would basically replicate the code from the `contrib.auth` package (plus passing initial values to the form).

My question, then, is this: Is there a simpler alternative, one that would get by without copying code? Any hints would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request *is* passed into the form on GET - see line 54 of django.contrib.auth.views. So yes, extending the form to take the username seems like the best way to go. Something like (untested):

```
class ExtendedAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if request is not None:
            username = request.get_username_however()
            initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
            initial_default = {'username': username}
            initial_default.update(initial)
            kwargs['initial'] = initial_default
        super(ExtendedAuthForm, self).__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Indeed, I stand corrected (cf. [django.contrib.auth.views](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L55)). Your code works perfectly, too. Thanks a lot, this has been very helpful!