# Access request.GET or inject a variable in Django's auth login/registration form

Tags: django, django-templates, django-authentication

I have a custom form using Django's auth library and I want some users to click on a link to login/register that will pre-populate the email field, without them having to enter their email (avoid entering it manually and make sure the user uses the email we have on file).

A link like this: `/account/login?email=name@domain.com`

However on the receiving page, I can't use this as Django doesn't permit in templates:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required="" value="{{ request.GET.get('email', '') }}">
```

If there is a way to inject a variable in Django's auth template, I don't know how since the view is not accessible.

Is there a way to access `request.GET.get()` in the templates, or is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:
@dirkbo's comment makes sense, however the request is always `None` in my form, which is called like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/register/', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=CustomRegistrationForm))
    ...
]
```

Comment: Something similiar to this should do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5193565/453910

Comment: Thanks for your comment friend, it pushed me in the correct direction, but `request` is always `None` in `class CustomUserForm(RegistrationForm)`